# Container Insights - Containerstats Dashboard

Tags: azure, containers, dashboard, azure-log-analytics

is it possible to show the [Podstats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwxpn.png) of AKS on a shared Dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Why not, you would just need to pull that data from the OMS and create a custom dashboard from those queries.

if you click on the individual entry it will navigate to the OMS instance and show you the query needed to get that data.

Comment: Yes, but not for 
Monitor - Containers (preview)

Answer (score 0):

Danny, Unfortunately there is no simple "click to pin this chart" functionality available currently in Container Insights (more modern name for that thing is Azure Monitor for Containers). We're looking to add it within a couple of months.

The chart does a query to Log Analytics store and goes into a bit of custom processing on the data received to render the chart. You can go to your cluster, "Metrics" on the menu on the left and chart the same thing there. You can pin from the metrics. Let me know if you need help with that I can provide more detailed instructions...